# Using pigpio and hardware PWM simultaneously

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie, pwm, pigpio

I am using pigpio to read 4 inputs. Everything works fine. And the entire process is a bit long and memory consuming. I also have to use one PWM output. I am planning to use the hardware PWM (pin 12 or 33) of the raspberry pi. My doubt is, using pigpio and hardware PWM pin simultaneously is safe or not?

```
import pigpio
import Rpi.GPIO as HWPWM


#using pigpio for reading 4 pins

pigpio.exceptions = True
GPIO=[23, 24, 25, 26]
for pinNr in GPIO:
    pi.set_mode(pinNr, pigpio.INPUT)


#uisng hardware PWM to set a pin

HWPWM.setmode(HWPWM.BOARD)
HWPWM.setup(12, HWPWM.OUT)

pwm12 = HWPWM.PWM(12, 0.5)
#50% duty cycle
pwm12.start(50)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing there.  You are trying to use RPi.GPIO to provide hardware PWM.  RPi.GPIO has no support for hardware PWM.

Comment: how to use hardware PWM?  That is what I got from a website.

Comment: Try a different web-site?  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM